# Date validations with bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-datepicker

Using bootstrap-datepicker.
There are two textboxes for StartDate & EndDate. I'm trying to set validations when user changes the date in any of these two textboxes.
At page load both boxes have current date.

Test Cases:
When user sets..
1. startDate beyond current date, set startDate=endDate
2. startDate beyond endDate, set endDate=startDate
3. endDate beyond current date, set endDate=current Date
4. endDate below startDate, set startDate=endDate

Case 1 fails. Say today is Jan 11, 2016 and I set the startDate as Jan 12, 2016, it doesn't change to Jan 11, 2011 but remains as Jan 12, 2016.

Also, Case 3 fails.

Is something wrong in my logic.

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/snh6eh9p/2/

**JS:**

```
function validateDates(dateType) {
  //dateType is to know if this function was fired by changing startdate or enddate
  //end-date must always be >= start-date
  var today = new Date();
  var startDate = new Date($(".txtStartDate").val());
  var endDate = new Date($(".txtEndDate").val());

  switch (dateType) {
    case 1:
    case "1":
      //if startDate is changed
      if (startDate > today) {
        setTriggerDates(endDate, 1); //set startDate=enddate         
      } else if (startDate > endDate) {
        setTriggerDates(startDate, 2); //set endDate=startDate
      }
      break;
    case 2:
    case "2":
      //if endDate is changed                    
      if (endDate > today) {
        setTriggerDates(today, 2); //set endDate=today
      } else if (endDate < startDate) {
        setTriggerDates(endDate, 1); //set startDate=endDate
      }
      break;
  }
}

function setTriggerDates(newDate, applyTo) {
  //applyTo determines, which textfield the value should be applied to.
  //if 1, then change value of txtStartDate,
  //if 2, then change value of txtEndDate  

  //populate date into the date fields
  var today = new Date(newDate);
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

  switch (applyTo) {
    case 1:
    case "1":
      $(".txtStartDate").val(today);
      break;
    case 2:
    case "2":
      $(".txtEndDate").val(today);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated your jsfiddle to fix the issue http://jsfiddle.net/snh6eh9p/4/.

Only change I did is call validateDates on hide event instead of changeDate event

```
$(".txtStartDate").datepicker()
.on("hide", function(ev) {
    validateDates(1);
});

$(".txtEndDate").datepicker()
.on("hide", function(ev) {
    validateDates(2);
});
```